# In which unicode encoding is the euro sign, which I can give to php's iconv?

Tags: php, character-encoding, iconv, euro

This works in php cli (on the command line),

```
php >  echo bin2hex(iconv("utf-8","iso-8859-1","\xc3\xa9"));
e9
```

That is, because I know the name of the unicode encoding of u20ac: latin-1, which is a part of  iso-8859-1.

I want to do the same for the euro sign,

```
php > echo bin2hex(iconv("utf-8","...","\xe2\x82\xac"));
20ac
```

What is the name of the encoding of the euro sign, which should be filled in on the ... ?

Comment: Whatever encoding you want to convert to!

Comment: Your question seems to have the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you really asking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should convert to `UTF-16`. Did I win? :-)

Seriously now, that would give you `fffeac20`. Close enough, but not exactly.

However, I suspect you're looking for the html entity for the Euro sign, which would be either `&euro;` or `&#x20ac;`